# Python-How to send a dataframe to external API (push)

Tags: python

[image]

I am wondering how to send this dataframe to external API?

Comment: do you want the data like your payload?

Comment: @TarequzzamanKhan No this is provided my xtremepush.
I want to pass the dataframe (df) as mentioned to the external api and using payload identiferes,apptoken.

Comment: You can convert a pandas Dataframe to Joson easily `df.to_joson()`

Comment: @TarequzzamanKhan I tell you what I want to do.
Basically,I want to pass df values as mentioned in the screenshot with Payload values to response.

can I call you or email please?

Comment: tareqcse12@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your dataframe into json file using `pandas.to_json()`, read that file and pass it as data in the post call of requests.

```
df_json_dict = json.loads(df.to_json(orient='records'))
requests.post(url, data=df_json_dict)
```

Comment: Can you help me please.
I dont know how to pass (df) with payload identifers and api key to external api

Comment: thanks
Can you tell me what will happen to payload then and api key

Comment: I am still not clear what you want to do. If you want to make a  POST call and pass the dataframe to that POST API, then what I have written can be used. Please elaborate in clear terms.

Answer (score 0):

In case the answer is still not clear, I will summarise the thing:

create your pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=',')
```

create the stream

```
import io, requests
stream = io.StringIO()
```

convert dataframe to csv stream

```
dataframe.to_csv(stream, sep=';', encoding='utf-8', index = False)
```

start stream from the beginning

```
stream.seek(0)
```

put the request using stream

```
file_upload_resp = requests.put(url, data=stream)
```